# h:inputText inside a h:dataTable does not preserve its state after clicking a commandButton with immediate true

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, mojarra

I need to display some entities in a h:dataTable that must be editable. The user can add and remove entities from this table. The problem is that when I add an entity clicking the button "Add" the state of what the user typed is gone.

I'm running Mojarra 2.1.7-jbossorg-1 (20120227-1401)

This is the first time the view is displayed, as you can see the dataTable is empty:
[image]

Then I click add and the following is showed:
[image]

I typed some values in the inputs:
[image]

I clicked "Add" again and as you can see the values that I typed of the first row are gone:
[image]

I need to be able to keep the state of the rows until I finish the edition and that's until I click the button "Save".

I also tried with **rowStatePreserved**="true" attribute of the h:dataTable and this is what happens:

Just after I typed something in the first row and I click add:
[image]

The first row state is preserved but the second row added has the same values as the first one even though I haven't typed anything in it yet.

**Code**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:oms="http://aom.org/oms"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <title>Testing</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="myForm" prependId="false">  
        <h:dataTable value="#{testingBean.persons}" var="person" border="1" rowStatePreserved="true">
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Name</f:facet>
                <h:inputText value="#{person.name}"/>
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Age</f:facet>
                <h:inputText value="#{person.age}"/>
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <h:commandButton action="#{testingBean.remove(person)}" value="Remove" immediate="true"/>
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
        <h:commandButton action="#{testingBean.add()}" value="Add" immediate="true"/>
        <h:commandButton action="#{testingBean.save()}" value="Save" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

**TestingBean.java:**

```
package org.aom.oms.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.enterprise.inject.Model;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TestingBean {  


    private List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<TestingBean.Person>();


    public List<Person> getPersons() {
        return persons;
    }

    public void setPersons(List<Person> persons) {
        this.persons = persons;
    }


    //Inner class for testing purpose
    public class Person {
        private String name;
        private Integer age;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public Integer getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        public void setAge(Integer age) {
            this.age = age;
        }
    }

    public void save() {
        System.out.println("Saving...");
        //myRepository.save(persons);
    }

    public void add() {
        persons.add(new Person());
    }

    public void remove(Person person) {
        persons.remove(person);
    }

}
```

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I can't remove the immediate attributes from "Add" and "Remove" commandButtons because my "unit-of-work" is to validate and save the data until I click the "Save" button.

Comment: What you're asking for is in practice impossible to achieve. You say you want to perform validation when you click on `save` button, so when you reach that moment you could have introduced, for example, a person with an age composed by letters. How do you want the model to keep that value if you have an `Integer` type for the age? You have to remove the `immediate` attributes and let the validation perform when each person is added. By the way, try to fix your question, even the code is [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), which is good, the images you posted are painful.

Comment: @XtremeBiker actually it is possible, see my answer.

Comment: Where did you read that `<h:dataTable>` has a `rowStatePreserved` attribute? This does not exist at all. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/dataTable.html

Comment: @BalusC From JSF 2.1 (Mojarra) Javadoc UIData http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.1/javadocs/javax/faces/component/UIData.html#isRowStatePreserved%28%29 even though the property is not documented in tld of HtmlDataTable the property exists because HtmlDataTable extends UIData and it was introduced in JSF 2.1

Comment: @BalusC anyway if by any chance you have a better idea for this scenario I'd be glad if you can answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using h:dataTable use Tomahawk [t:datatable](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk20/tagdoc/t_dataTable.html)

> The MyFacesDataTable extends the standard JSF DataTable by two
>   important features:
>
> - Possiblity to save the state of the DataModel.
> - Support for clickable sort headers (see SortHeader component).

These attributes let you do what you want:

> **preserveRowStates** (boolean): Indicates whether the state for each
>   row should not be discarded before the datatable is rendered again.
>   Setting this to true might be hepful if an input component inside the
>   datatable has no valuebinding and the value entered in there should be
>   displayed again. This will only work reliable if the datamodel of the
>   datatable did not change either by sorting, removing or adding rows.
>   Default: false
>
> **forceIdIndexFormula** (String): formula that overrides the default
>   row index in the construction of table's body components. Example : #{myRowVar.key} > Warning, the EL should evaluate to a unique value for each row !

Comment: I guess Tomahawk uses a kind of buffer for that and submits the whole table to the model at once. However, doing that the way you're asking for is unattainable.